# Function key is always turned on in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10

The function key is always ON after I updated Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 17.
For example, normally, when I want to mute. I used <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but now, it is <kbd>F1</kbd> only.
It is really annoying since sometimes I want to use the shortcuts to execute my program.

I have tried many ways like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>NumLk</kbd> to turn off but it's not working. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the shift button.

In my case <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> turns off <kbd>fn</kbd>

Comment: This is what resolve my problem with "function key always on", so, for me, this would been the answer to the question. Maybe not for other problems, but in my case it works... and i don't think that reputation is so important to comment a post, nobody have a reputation when answers for the first time...

Comment: Agreed. It's hardly an answer since it's speculative/doesn't deliver an argumentation why it should work. Anyway, my flag was denied in review (which makes and once again made sure that reputation differences don't influence the content in a negative way).